# splinter works in interactive but not as script

Tags: python, splinter

I am using Python Splinter to automate downloading information.

As part of the browser interaction, I wish to fill a text box on a web page with a string.

If I run python3.4 interactively, cut and paste from my program each Splinter command one at a time, I can watch each line executed as a response on a firefox browser and it all works; but when I execute the program, the command to find the text box fails with this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:

The Splinter commands are
   browser.find_by_id('addMore_institution').click()
   browser.find_by_id('addMoreText_institution').fill(institution+"\n")
```

Using inspect element in Firefox for the textbox is:

```
<input style="background-image: url(&quot;/static/images/common/icon_search_grey.png&quot;); cursor: default;" autocomplete="off" id="addMoreText_institution" class="addMoreTextbox ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Find an existing institution or group" data-entitytype="institution" type="text">
```

I've tried using `find_by_xpath` and other Splinter fin_by commands but to no avail.
Can anyone suggest how I can get the program to work?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem was solved adding a sleep(12) immediately prior to the find_by_id command. The program then continues and bombs on another lines which is solved by adding a sleep(12) immediately prior.

In posts about selenium there is a wait until visible code.
Is there an equivalent in Splinter?